How to Perform Post-Hoc Analysis of Interactions in Repeated Measures ANOVA with Two Within-Subjects Factors Using SPSS
I am currently conducting a repeated measures ANOVA with two within-subjects factors. The analysis revealed a significant interaction, and I added the following command for post-hoc analysis:
/EMMEANS=TABLES(IV1*IV2) COMPARE(IV1) ADJ(BONFERRONI)
While the results showed significant effects, I have some doubts about the analysis outcome, so I am seeking advice.
When I compared the results of this command with the results from paired t-test(uncorrected), the values from pared t-test are identical to the results produced by the SPSS command. This leads me to suspect that the Bonferroni correction might not have been applied correctly.
Could there be an issue with the command I used? If so, what would be the correct command to apply the Bonferroni correction properly in SPSS?

Welcome to CV. Questions that focus on programming (e.g. how do I do X in SPSS) are off-topic here, though I believe the core of your issue is the multiplicity adjustment. Bonferroni, like pretty much any other multiple testing correction, scales with the number of tests. How many levels of your factor/interaction are there and/or how many tests are you performing? If only one, the adjustment will correct using $\alpha / 1$ which is identical to an uncorrected test (and correctly so).

FWIW, I tried with some of my own data, and I get different CIs and p-values from RM-ANOVA with bonferroni correction and from paired samples t-test with no correction. Which parameters are identical for you?

I'm sorry that my question was inappropriate, and I'll be more careful next time. My design included two within-subject factors (IV1, IV2): IV1 had 2 levels, and IV2 had 3. RM ANOVA revealed a significant interaction, and I conducted 3 post-hoc tests comparing IV1 levels within each IV2 level. The paired t-test yielded identical CIs and p-values.

OK, I looked into this more closely and it seems you are correct. SPSS does not seem to apply Bonferroni correction to pairwise comparisons from RM-ANOVA even when you choose it from the drop-down menu or use the syntax BONFERRONI command. In this tutorial they say, somewhere in the middle, that in their "enhanced" tutorial they will show how to "trick SPSS Statistics into applying a Bonferroni adjustment for multiple comparisons which it would otherwise not do". However, I couldn't find this enhanced tutorial. Very annoying.
However, as alluded to in the comment by @PBulls, you can easily conduct Bonferroni correction manually - divide your pre-determined alpha level (often 0.05) with the number of comparisons you will make.

Seems to me that if you have paired comparisons, you are only comparing two things and that yields one test statistic. Thus there is no multiplicity of tests, and that means the Bonferroni correction is for only a set of size 1, hence no correction at all.
